# How to Create Symlink Dynamically for Dynamically Created File in a Folder

Tags: linux, symlink

I create a file based on time or something like that for stylesheet. It is fingerprinting filename to avoiding cached version on web browser. Example file name: `style_1374065326.css`.

I want to create a symlink for any newly created file in another folder. Is it possible?

If not, is it possible to create a folder `CSS/` in another folder where I want to create symlinks and that folder have symlinks for all the similar file names in another directory where files can come dynamically.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to symlink all CSS-files in a given directory into another simply do:

```
$ cd /path/to/symlinkdir
$ ln -s /path/to/orgdir/*.css .
```

if a file is already symlinked (or otherwise existing), you will get a warning like `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/path/to/orgdir/style_1374065326.css': File exists` which you can safely ignore.

if you want this to be *fully automated*, you might want to check `inotify` to monitor the source directory and run the symlink command whenever a `.css` is created therein.

Comment: I do not know if this is the only way, but possibly the answer is the only way. The C prog after so long is looking tough task.

Comment: @SatyaPrakash the answer is very simple, if what you want to do is to have each file in one directory symlinked to another directory. if this is not exactly what you want, please specify

Comment: No,  want symlink for files created dynamically. It can also work that all files of certain type involved.

Comment: @SatyaPrakash my method is not concerned how the original files are created, meaning it *will* work with files that were created dynamically. what is missing?